# Why does the variable give me a TypeError but the function doesn't?

Tags: python, django, typeerror

I'm trying to run the following code but "full_name" gives me the following error.

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'CharField' and 'str'

```
from django.db import models

class user(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    full_name = first_name + ' ' + last_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

When I change the "full_name" from a variable to a function, the TypeError goes away and my code works fine.

```
from django.db import models

class user(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
    def full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name()
```

Why does the variable give me a TypeError but the function doesn't? Don't they do the same thing?

Comment: In your first snippet you have: 'full_name =', did you mean: 'self.full_name = '?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statements on class level are evaluated on start up. Statements in methods are evaluated when the method is called.

In the first example the expression is evaluated on start up; against the class attribute values. Effectively, you are doing `models.CharField(max_length=200) + ' ' + models.CharField(max_length=200)`, but you can't concatenate a `CharField` with a string.

In the second example the expression is performed when the method is called on an instance; against the **values** of both fields, which are strings.

Answer (score 0):

It gives error because full_name is actually a variable in user class. But fucntion is returning a string. Class user never actually runs so you cant's define a variable which doesn't subclass django.models.